# Trailing slash causes page to 404

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a site that's built with PHP and I'm using the `.htaccess` file to remove the `.php` extension.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This works fine and means that I can access `/file.php` by doing `/file`.  However if I put a trailing slash at the end of the URL I get a 404 error.  I've tried quite a few things but I can't get it work.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same problem.  If I add the trailing slash it 404's because its trying to take me to file/.php